# How can I upload files with the form element type file?

Tags: 8, forms

I want to upload a file and I have to use form element type as 'file'. In submit function I am not able to get any proper data related to the file which I am uploading. SO Can anyone please help me to resolve this. Please find the below code:

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  $form['test_CERTIFICATE'] = [
    '#type' => 'file',
    '#title' => $this->t('Certificate'),
    '#description' => $this->t('Your Certificate (.pem file)').': '.\Drupal::state()->get('test_CERTIFICATE_NAME'),           
  ];
  
  return parent::buildForm($form, $form_state);
}
```

Submit function:

```
public function submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {
  parent::submitForm($form, $form_state);

  $validators = array('file_validate_extensions' => array('pem'));
  $files = file_save_upload('test_CERTIFICATE', $validators, 'public://certfiles', FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);
  $file = File::load($files[0]);
  if ($file) {
    kint($files); exit;
    // here control is not coming
    $file->setPermanent();
    $file->save();
  }
}
```

Comment: Refer github repository for custom form with file upload. https://github.com/nitin-kawane/custom-form-with-file-upload-in-drupal-8

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had the same problem with the `file` form element. Solved this by using `managed_file` and providing the upload location and validators in the form element:

```
$form['test_CERTIFICATE'] = [
  '#type' => 'managed_file',
  '#title' => $this->t('Certificate'),
  '#upload_location' => 'private://certfiles',
  '#upload_validators' => [
    'file_validate_extensions' => ['pem'],
  ],
];
```

Then in submit:

```
use Drupal\file\Entity\File;

$form_file = $form_state->getValue('test_CERTIFICATE', 0);
if (isset($form_file[0]) && !empty($form_file[0])) {
  $file = File::load($form_file[0]);
  $file->setPermanent();
  $file->save();
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your suggestion. even I got success with this method. But here, how can I prevent entry of duplicate files in the public folder. Because of this reason I opted for "file" type. in this we can do by using file_save_upload so..

Comment: The temporary file is deleted automatically, I think by default within 6 hours. If you don't want to wait you can delete it after you've saved the permanent file.

Comment: I am not telling about temporary file buddy. if i uploaded same file twice, that time its keeping both the files in the public folder by appending random number to latest file. this type of duplication am telling.

Comment: You could check for an existing file with the same name before you make the temporary file permanent.

Answer (score 16):

You can access files data uploaded through "file" field using the following code (from D8.5 core/modules/config/src/Form/ConfigImportForm.php)

```
$all_files = $this->getRequest()->files->get('files', []);
$file = $all_files['test_CERTIFICATE'];
$file_path = $file->getRealPath();
```

Comment: Would love to know reason for downvote. Unnecessarily complex, or bad practice?

Comment: I believe this is a more correct to the question, when you use `'#type' => 'file'` this is the way to get the file.

Comment: @almcnicoll The reason for the downvote was that there is no reason to get into this low level of file upload. It's just bad advice.

Comment: Upvoted. This is the clearest way of uploading unmanaged files. To obtain the original file name you may use `$file_name = $file->getClientOriginalName()`, and then save the file to the final location via `file_unmanaged_copy($file_path, "PATH/$file_name");`.

Comment: Thanks for posting, CamelCode. In certain advanced implementations, this information is useful. Upvoted.