# Image File field not getting updated

Tags: forms

Form function:

```
$form['upload_photo'] = array(
        '#type' => 'file',
        '#title' => t('Upload Your Photo'),
        '#title_display' => 'before',
        '#states' => array(
            'visible' => array(
                ':input[name="testimonial_type"]' => array('value' => 'Text'),
            ),
        ),
        '#prefix' => '<tr><td>',
        '#suffix' => '</td></tr>',
    );
```

Submit function:

```
$field_collection_item = entity_create('field_collection_item', array('field_name' => 'field_text_testimonial_info'));
$file_d = $form_state['values']['upload_photo'];
                $file = file_load($file_d);
                $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
                file_save($file);
                file_usage_add($file, 'user', 'TYPE', $file->fid);
                $file_info = image_get_info($file->uri);
                $file_arr = array(
                'fid' => $file->fid,
                );
                $field_collection_item->field_client_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0] = $file_arr;
                $field_collection_item->setHostEntity('user', $user);
                $field_collection_item->save();
```

After submit I am getting below error:

- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$uri in file_save() (line 614 of /public_html/includes/file.inc).
- Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$filename in views_data_export_file_presave() (line 278 of /public_html/sites/all/modules/contrib/views_data_export/views_data_export.module).
- PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'uri': INSERT INTO {file_managed} (filesize, status, timestamp) VALUES (:db_insert_placeholder_0, :db_insert_placeholder_1, :db_insert_placeholder_2); Array ( [:db_insert_placeholder_0] => 0 [:db_insert_placeholder_1] => 1 [:db_insert_placeholder_2] => 1535026403 ) in drupal_write_record() (line 7386 of /public_html/includes/common.inc).

Kindly help me to solve it out

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help [How to upload file in drupal8 forms with form element type file?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/239700/how-to-upload-file-in-drupal8-forms-with-form-element-type-file)

I see for your use case it makes more sense to use [Managed file type](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21src%21Element%21ManagedFile.php/class/ManagedFile/8.2.x).

A couple of observations, something you should look at,

- It seems you are getting SQL errors due to trying to upload a file which is already present in the table, you should check why this happens and perhaps programmatically change the name of the file if it already exists. See [file_save_data](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21modules%21file%21file.module/function/file_save_data/8.2.x)
- Errors from views, not sure where you are trying to submit this form, but it is clearly breaking something in views_data_export or it maybe because of the next point.
- Lastly, check the link above for how to properly handle file uploads in form, it looks like `file_save($file);` is breaking for you due to missing `uri`