# Create nodes from a JSON file uploaded in a form by an user

Tags: forms, files, 8

I've got this form:

```php
 $form['import_json'] = [
      '#type' => 'file',
      '#description' => $this->t('Allowed extensions: json'),
      '#title' => $this->t('Import your JSON\'s file.'),
    ];

    $form['submit'] = [
      '#type' => 'submit',
      '#value' => $this->t('Import'),
    ];
```

I have to use `'#type' => 'file'` because AFAIK managed_file doesn't allow json file and file is the only type left.

I need to be able to get the uploaded file when the user submit the form to be able to convert the JSON's data to create nodes of a certain type.

My function is already created and it looks like this:

```php
protected function createActualite(string $json)
  {

    $jsonstring = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    foreach ($jsonstring as $field) {
      $node = Node::create([
        'type' => 'import_content', // Machine name de notre content type 'actualité'
        'title' => $field['titre'],
        'body' => $field['body'],
      ]);
      $node->save();
    }
  }
```

The problem is that I can't find a way to properly get the uploaded file, I tried the same way that we do with managed_file

```php
$file = File::load($field['import_json']);
        $file->setPermanent();
        $file->save();
```

but it doesn't work, also this (which is 10yo) doesn't do the trick either [gist](https://gist.github.com/brockboland/790842)

If someone can lead me to arrive to save this file or to any doc, I would greatly appreciate.

Comment: You might want to walk through the [csvimport](https://github.com/xurizaemon/csvimport) sample module which I co-maintain. It shows you how to handle the file upload and shows you how to implements a batch process to prevent timeouts on node creation when trying to create many 1000 nodes at once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I made it works, first I get the file's path using the solution given [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/257895/95193)

and then once I got the path, I'm reading the file using

```php
$file = file_get_contents($file_path);
```

then calling my function createActualite($file); and it creates all the nodes up to the content of the JSON as expected.